# Colors from RGB are not correct Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

So I have a 2D object that you can change the color of using buttons, and each button will change the sprite of the object. I have a sprite for red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple.

Now I have a particle system (A child of the object stated before) that I want to change the startColor property of to the same color as whatever the 2D object's sprite is. I'm using this code (Attached to the 2D object that you can change the sprite of):

```
        var sprite = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        var startColor = gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().startColor;

        if (sprite == red) startColor = new Color(255, 29, 0);
        else if (sprite == orange) startColor = new Color(254, 32, 0);
        else if (sprite == yellow) startColor = new Color(254, 215, 0);
        else if (sprite == green) startColor = new Color(0, 254, 32);
        else if (sprite == blue) startColor = new Color(0, 37, 254);
        else if (sprite == purple) startColor = new Color(178, 0, 255);

        gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().startColor = startColor;
```

All the new Colors() I'm trying to create from RGB. So I took the RGB value of the all color sprites and plugged them in. And when I executed the code, the color of the particles doesn't match the object's sprite color.

NOTES: I'm running this on android, and the material for the particle system is plain white so it shouldn't tint the color.

I put the RGB values from the color sprites in over five times. But it doesn't match the sprites! I don't know what's wrong... if you need me to attach the color sprite images, just ask.

Comment: Please clean up the code, it's very hard to read it as it is. You don't need to reload the same sprite every time, just store `gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite` in a variable, ie `var sprite=gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;`

Comment: What color do you get?

Comment: You can also store `gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject` in a variable. As it is, the code is unreadable

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've misused the [`Color()` constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-ctor.html). Referring to the documentation, take note that parameters for the constructor should be float values in the range of [0,1]. If you don't want to calculate the appropriate values to supply, just divide them by 255:

```
new Color(0, 37/255f, 254/255f);
```

Alternatively, you may use the [`Color32()` constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32-ctor.html), which takes int values in the range of [0,255]:

```
new Color32(0, 37, 254);
```

`Color` and `Color32` can be implicitly converted to each other, so don't worry about casting issues. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: `new Color(0, 37/255F, 254/255F);` to prevent *integer* division

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks! Good catch, that could lead to some unexpected results otherwise.

Comment: That looks like a defect in the constructor then, it should throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: @Stijn I think a lot of Unity's methods clamp input values within the acceptable range (or at least don't break when you exceed the min/max) - though it would be handy if they gave you more indications you were using the wrong one.

Comment: @Serlite It works! Oddly or not. Thanks, and I have no questions.

Comment: `Color32` doesn't have a constructor with just 3 arguments, you need to provide the alpha as the fourth. e.g. `new Color32(0, 37, 254, 255)`

Comment: I tried it both with dividing by 255f and by using Color32 with 4 bytes. Both work. Thanks to everyone that helped.