# Smoke Opacity Relative to Player Health

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system

I have a particle system emitting smoke. I am attempting to make the apparent thickness or darkness of the smoke relative to the health of the player. To do this, I am applying the relative vehicle damage (0 to 100) to the alpha of the particle system start color. Even when I divide the player damage by some number (6 is what the snipped below uses), the darkness of the smoke sees way beyond what I expect. For example, an alpha of 30 looks as dark as 255. Any thoughts? Better way to do this?

```
var smokeColor = smokeParticles.startColor;
float smokeAlpha = (255 / 100) * (vehicleDamage / 6);
if (smokeAlpha > 255)
{
    smokeAlpha = 255;
}

print("smoke alpha " + smokeAlpha.ToString());
var newcolor = new Color(smokeColor.r, smokeColor.g, smokeColor.b, smokeAlpha);
smokeParticles.startColor = newcolor;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Colors from RGB are not correct Unity C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38899817/colors-from-rgb-are-not-correct-unity-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `255` or values that are more than `1f` to a parameter that expects `0f` to `1f` values. That's why its not working. `1f` is completely opaque and alpha of `0` is completely transparent. Make `smokeAlpha` a value between `0f` and `1f` then pass it to your  new Color then it should work.

Your `smokeColor.r`,`smokeColor.g` and `smokeColor.b` looks fine because you are getting them from the `smokeParticles` variable and you are not modifying them like the way you are modifying the alpha variable(`smokeAlpha`).

If you really want the `smokeAlpha` variable to use the `0` to `255` value range then you have to divide your final value by `255`.

```
var smokeColor = smokeParticles.startColor;
float smokeAlpha = (255 / 100) * (vehicleDamage / 6);
if (smokeAlpha > 255)
{
    smokeAlpha = 255;
}

smokeAlpha = smokeAlpha / 255f; //Add this

print("smoke alpha " + smokeAlpha.ToString());
var newcolor = new Color(smokeColor.r, smokeColor.g, smokeColor.b, smokeAlpha);
smokeParticles.startColor = newcolor;
```

Comment: yep... exactly what I missed. Thank you.